Return and Function
Can somebody explain the behavior of Return inside a function? I know that Function and If have the attribute HoldAll or HoldRest, but the following seems a bit strange considering that Return does not always return its argument. Consider the 3 functions:
f1 := (
   If[# == 1, Return["a"]];
   "b"
   ) &
f2 := Function[x,
  If[x == 1, Return["a"]];
  "b"
  ]
f3[x_] := (If[x == 1, Return["a"]]; "b")

Now with this:
f1[1]
f1[2]

Return["a"]
b

and
f2[1]
f2[2]

Return["a"]
b

and finally
f3[1]
f3[2]

a
b


It's simple. Trace all expressions. The functions return the prescibed result without processing it,  the case f3 for If[True, Return[a];b] is processing the Return with an exit before ;b]

@Domen I believe this one is closer :) .

@xzczd, well, but the answer in your question is not particularly useful or explanatory, while Leonid gives quite a detailed explanation in the other one :)

@Domen I'd say Daniel's comment therein looks quite valuable in my view :) .

Try f1 := (If[# == 1, Return["a", CompoundExpression]]; "b") &. But it's not very robust. Further, I can't explain presently why this works with Identity and fails without it: f1 := Identity@(If[# == 1, 2; Return["a", Function]]; "b") &.
